# Chrome Opening Bypass

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

I have a hotkey string of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>T</kbd>  set to open a new chrome browser even when one is not open, but I also use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>T</kbd>  to open a new tab when Chrome is already open. It seems that the keystroke bypasses Chrome. Is there any way to set it so that it would only open a new Google Chrome window if there isn't already one open?

Comment: How did you set this shortcut? Why don't you just use Ctrl+T to open a new tab?

Comment: @Seth Changed it to Ctrl + T and then Chrome opened one as well. I set it with key bindings in the Ubuntu Keyboard settings

Comment: No, I mean Chrome's default shortcut is that Ctrl+T opens a new tab, so you could leave Ctrl+Alt+T to open a new window and Ctrl+T to open a new tab. Either way. Can I see your configuration for this shortuct?

Comment: Im being an idiot I dont use Ctrl + Alt + T.. see edit

Comment: So can I see your existing configuration though?